# Webpack cannot use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webpack

I'm starting using webpack (version 3) and when I try to use jQuery from my "app.js" file then nothing happens:
I npm install --save jquery and:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
$('body').css('backgroundColor', '#DD0000')

document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

And when I try changing the css using document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
it tells me "cannot read property style of null"

But for the rest it's working, I mean I tried this successfully :

```
import json from "./test"
console.log(json)
```

Here is my HTML head part:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Webpack</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
   <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here is my webpack config :

```
const path = require("path");
const uglify = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: ["babel-loader"],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new uglify(),
    ]
}
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inserted your script in the `<head>` section. And since JS is *blocking*, it's executed right there, before the `<body>` is parsed and exists (so it's `null`).

If you want this to work, either put your script at the end of the document, right before the closing `</body>` tag, or wait for the document to be loaded:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 // Here, you can use document.body
});
```

or, in jQuery syntax:

```
$(function() {
 // Here, you can use document.body
});
```